# Rollover IRA and Roth IRA Contribution Limit?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, contribution, limits, rollover-ira

I have a 401k from a prior employer that I quit from a couple of years ago.
As I cannot invest in it any longer I have decided to move it into a "Rollover IRA".

I already have a Roth IRA.  Are my contribution limits affected in my Rollover IRA since I am only allowed to put in 6k yearly in my Roth IRA?

Basically my question is can I put 6k$ in my roth ira and that does not count against my contribution limit for my rollover ira?  If so what is the max contribution I can make to my Rollover IRA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits), the $6K contribution limit or for *all IRAs combined, both Traditional and Roth*, so you cannot contribute $6k to each.

Note that a rollover is not a contribution, so it does not affect your limit (I think you know this, but just making it explicit).

Comment: Yes. +1. Also note, the rules for rollover needing to stay segregated from the traditional IRA is gone. These funds can join the existing IRA, if any.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not understanding it - sort of noobish to Rollover IRA.  Does this mean if I contribute 6k to my ROTH IRA I cannot contribute to my Rollover IRA?  Sounds like you are saying I cannot contribute to Rollover IRA.  If that is the case I dont see any benefit to rolling it over then...bummer ?

Comment: @JonH rolling over is **not** contributing.  That means you can rollover **and** contribute $6000.

Comment: @RonJohn - I understand that - assume I rolled over my entire 401k I know that isnt a contribution.  What I am asking is now that its rolled over lets say I rolled over 500k.  Can I then fund 6k to my ROTH IRA and another say 6k to my rollover?

Comment: @JonH You are right that you cannot contribute any more, but there may still be value in rolling over to get access to more investments. You can also decide going forward how much to contribute to each depending on your tax situation, but the total for the year cannot be more that $6K.

Comment: @JonH "Can I then **fund** 6k to my ROTH IRA **and another** say 6k to my rollover?"  The first sentence of DStanley's answer says, "the $6K contribution limit or for all IRAs combined, both Traditional and Roth, so **you cannot contribute $6k to each**".  I don't know how much more clearly it can be stated.

Comment: @DStanley - thats kind of a bummer...but I now understand the answer.  Thank you sir.

Comment: @RonJohn - the  or in that sentence confused me: `the $6K contribution limit or for all IRAs combined`